# Oracle Workflow error-358: Activity result code 'SUCCESS' has no transition defined for it

Tags: oracle, workflow

Hello I am getting below error when I am trying to save the workflow.

> 358: Activity result code 'SUCCESS' has no transition defined for it. 
>   All valid result codes must be modeled with specific transitions or a
>    transition.

I have added a lookup type `Result_status` under which I have added 4 lookup
codes- `Mail_sending_Error`, `Unexpected_error`, `Attachment_error` and `SUCCESS`.

I have linked all 4 lookup codes to the function where I am attaching my result_status lookup type. Then also I am getting the error above.

[image: Error pic 2]
[image: Error pic 1]

Does anybody have any idea regarding this error.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is not with the process you show in your diagram, but it is inside the sub-processes on the end activity(s). Update the end activity(s) in generate_email to make sure the result type on the Function tab is set to <None>. 
( Note: Your return values on end activities are the result type defined for the process )